# Canvas js column chart is not rendering from JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, canvasjs

I have tried this in canvas js and I have no previous experience regarding this issue.please give me a hint to fix this.

I have a method which returning JSON string like below and its in a asp.net asmx web service.

```html
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
[{"x":1,"y":11.211000000000004},{"x":2,"y":2.9419999999999984},{"x":3,"y":-1.125},{"x":4,"y":2.7779999999999987},{"x":5,"y":-12.715000000000002},{"x":6,"y":12.482},{"x":7,"y":19.523000000000003},{"x":8,"y":-2.3674999999999997},{"x":9,"y":1.7780000000000005},{"x":10,"y":15.724},{"x":11,"y":40.994}]
</string>
```

I want to insert this x and y datapoints into my canvas js bar chart so I have set an ajax call to my asmx asp.net service method like below

```html
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:  'Services/ForecastingMainControllerService.asmx/CalculateLeavingGraph',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var dataPoints = [];
                    
                    for (var i = 0; i <data.length; i++) {
                   
                        dataPoints.push({ x: data[i].x, y: data[i].y });
                    }
                 

                        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                            axisX: {
                                title: "User IDs",
                            },
                            axisY: {
                                title: "Years",
                                
                            },
                        title: {
                            text: ""
                        },

                        data: [{
                            type: "column",
                            dataPoints: dataPoints
                        },

                        ]
                    });

                    chart.render();

                }
            });
```

Its going inside of the success function and data is full filled with returning JSON String.

But still graph is not rendering properly. Any hints or help ?

[image: Graph is not rendering still]

Answer (score 0):

CanvasJS accepts integral/float value but not string value for dataPoints. So try parsing the x, y value to int/float as shown below.

```
dataPoints.push({ x: parseInt(data[i].x), y: parseFloat(data[i].y) });
```